# Segmented Control Problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4, interface-builder

My program will crash if I press the segmented control buttons one after another.  For example, if i press the first one, then second, and third, it will crash.  Any ideas for what could be causing this.  I also release it and everything, really stumped here.  Any ideas.

Thanks

```
- (IBAction) segmentedControlIndexChanged {

switch (self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex) {
    case 0:
        [self mirror];
        break;
    case 1:
        [self exact];
        break;
    case 2:
        [self round];
        break;
}
}
```

I'm getting a EXC_BAD_ACESS

if that means anything, cause i'm not sure what that means

error on line 2179 of "/SourceCache/gdb/gdb-1510/src/gdb/macosx/macosx-nat-inferior.c" in function "macosx_kill_inferior_safe": (os/kern) failure (0x5x)

Comment: there are no problems in the code you posted. It is something in mirror, exact or round methods. Post the stack trace

Comment: `Command+Shift+Y` and you can debug it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EXEC_BAD_ACCESS means you are attempting to call a method on a deallocated instance. The tricky thing about fixing these errors is that it can happen well after the instance was released, so what you're doing at the time isn't necessarily what is causing the error.

Fortunately, there is a tool to help you. NSZombieEnabled

Go down to your executables folder in XCode, and right click on the app and click Get Info.

Go to the Arguments Tab, and click the plus button below variables to be set in the environment.

Call the new variable `NSZombieEnabled` and set it's value to `YES`

When you enable this, any instance that gets deallocated gets replaced by a Zombie object, and your console should display an object and "message sent to deallocated instance" which should help you track down your problem.